# What is the function/point of "config.sub"

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, install, software-installation

I'm trying to install some software from the command line.  There is a file called "config.sub".  Am I supposed to use this for something?

I haven't been able yet to find out by searching online what this file is supposed to do. I think part of the deal is I don't know how to ask the question correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

config.sub is one of files generated by autoconf. [Autoconf documentations](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html#index-g_t_0040command_007bconfig_002esub_007d-1837) states that it converts system aliases into full canonical names.

In short - you don't have to worry about it unless you're autoconf developer.